# Using Dall-E in google appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, openai-api

I know that it is possible to implement dall-e as a function in google sheets but I need your help to get it right.

openai is not defined and I don't know how to do it correctly.

```
function dalle() {

 var setsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
var apiKey = setsheet.getRange(8,2).getValue()

  response = openai.Image.create(
  prompt="a white siamese cat",
  n=1,
  size="1024x1024"
)
image_url = response['data'][0]['url']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You copied the documentation from the OpenAI documentation, but it's mentioned that's only working for node.js or python.

For Apps Script, you have to use `UrlFetch.fetch` with the correct endpoint.

Example:

```
function call() {

  var url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations';

  var options = {
    "method": 'POST',
    "headers": {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer YOUR_API_KEY`
    },
    "payload": JSON.stringify({
      "model": "image-alpha-001",
      "prompt": "a white siamese cat",
      "num_images": 1,
      "size": "256x256",
      "response_format": "url"
    }),
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  }
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var responseJson = response.getContentText();
  var responseData = JSON.parse(responseJson);
  Logger.log(responseData);
}
```

Reference:

[UrlFetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch)

[OpenAI authentification (see CURL method)](https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/authentication)